# Django tried these URL patterns, in this order

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

When I click on a link it always comes out **not found** error while on the `home` page it goes well. Here are my url patterns:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from App import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('qui_sommes_nous/', views.qui_sommes_nous, name='qui_sommes_nous'),
    path('equipe/', views.equipe, name='equipe'),
    path('galerie/', views.galerie, name='galerie'),
    path('avendre/', views.avendre, name='avendre'),
    path('alouer/', views.alouer, name='alouer'),
    path('realisation/', views.realisation, name='realisation'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('details_des_appartement/', views.details_des_appartement, name='details_des_appartement'),

   
]
```

please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths need to have a slash as prefix, so:

```
<a href="/contact/">contact</a>
```

for example. Not:

```
<a href="contact/">contact</a>
```

Better is to make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'contact' %}">contact</a>
```

Comment: Thank you it's ok but the home page what type of tag I have to put

Comment: @ouesergeGedeon: for the homepage it is the same, if you want to link to the homepage, you use `<a href="{% url 'index' %}">homepage</a>`.

Comment: Is there any way to remove unused CSS in Django with the output of the new file?